# android : communication myservice with other apps activity

Tags: android

I'm android programing in eclips (my english language is not good!).
I want that if a user types a character in other app that it first sends to my service and my service processes this character and feedback to that activity.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you already tried or what is not working?

Comment: it is my ask : how to communication my background service with other apps activity in Eclips IDE?